# delegation of :id when creating new instance

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I have three models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  has_many :dogs, :through => :employees
end

class Employee < ActiveRescord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :dogs
end

class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee

  delegate :id, :to => :employee, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true
end
```

This works perfectly fine and I can call dog.employee_id in my view. However, if I want to create a new instance in RailsAdmin (not when editing an existing object), I get this error:

```
RuntimeError at /dog/new
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

:allow_nil is set to true and delegations for other attributes work fine. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: may be the problem is calling `id` for nil object in /dog/new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a delegate to be able to access dog.employee_id.

The belongs_to relation already implies Dog will hold the foreign key to Employee and creates an employee_id attribute.